# AWS Glue ETL job failing with "Failed to delete key: parquet-output/_temporary"

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, etl, parquet, aws-glue

I'm running a Glue ETL job on a CSV datatable generated by a Glue Crawler. The Crawler hits a directory with the following structure

```
   s3 
      -> aggregated output
         ->datafile1.csv
         ->datafile2.csv
     ->datafile3.csv
```

These files are aggregated into a "aggregated-output" table which can be queried in athena successfully.

I am trying to convert this into a parquet file using an AWS Glue ETL job. The job is failing with

```
"py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
o92.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete key: parquet-output/_temporary"
```

I'm having trouble tracking down the root cause here

I've tried modifying the Glue job several ways. I made sure the IAM role assigned to the job has permission to delete folders on the bucket in question. Right now I'm using the default temp/script folders given by AWS. I've tried using folders on my s3 bucket but see a similar error

```
s3://aws-glue-temporary-256967298135-us-east-2/admin
s3://aws-glue-scripts-256967298135-us-east-2/admin/rt-5/13-ETL-Tosat
```

Sharing the full stacktrace below

```
19/05/10 17:57:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-32-29-36.us-east-2.compute.internal/172.32.29.36:8032
Container: container_1557510304861_0001_01_000002 on ip-172-32-1-101.us-east-2.compute.internal_8041
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Fri May 10 17:57:53 +0000 2019
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
End of LogType:stdout
Container: container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001 on ip-172-32-26-232.us-east-2.compute.internal_8041
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Fri May 10 17:57:54 +0000 2019
LogLength:9048
Log Contents:
null_fields []
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2019-05-10-17-47-48.py", line 40, in <module>
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options =
{
    "path": "s3://changed-s3-path-parquet-output/parquet-output"
}
, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 585, in from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 193, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 216, in write_from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 32, in write
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 28, in writeFrame
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1557510304861_0001/container_1557510304861_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o92.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete key: parquet-output/_temporary
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.delete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:689)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.delete(EmrFileSystem.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.cleanupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.abortJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:482)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.abortJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:123)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 1 exceptions thrown from 1 batch deletes
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.deleteAll(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:375)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.doSingleThreadedBatchDelete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1369)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.delete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:687)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: MultiObjectDeleteException thrown with 26 keys in error: parquet-output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20190510164114_0000_m_000001_1/part-00001-7288591a-dd6f-404a-9c24-1dd70b3ff4ff-c000.snappy.parquet, parquet-output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20190510164315_0000_m_000001_2/part-00001-7288591a-dd6f-404a-9c24-1dd70b3ff4ff-c000.snappy.parquet, parquet-output/_temporary/0/_temporary_$folder$
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.deleteAll(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:360)
... 59 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException: One or more objects could not be deleted (Service: null; Status Code: 200; Error Code: null; Request ID: 071747B6992918B9), S3 Extended Request ID: oTBHx76MMI70zuD86AWeq4+rXa3GalW6ptQFM91ceQwhB9SBJV9Z6qw1yG2Ar2DBOr06soLL5dE=
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.deleteObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:2084)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.DeleteObjectsCall.perform(DeleteObjectsCall.java:25)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.DeleteObjectsCall.perform(DeleteObjectsCall.java:11)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:80)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:176)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.deleteObjects(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:125)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.deleteAll(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:355)
... 59 more

End of LogType:stdout
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed this by creating a new IAM role with permissions to S3 and the AWSGlueServiceRole

Comment: Holy moly 1k views and no upvotes? I'm dying out here guys!

Comment: based on you description of the issue, the solution doesn't make sense...you said the role already has all the permissions why creating a new one with the same set of permissions?

Comment: Its been 2 years since I tackled this, but I think the issue was not having the AWSGlueServiceRole on the IAM role

Comment: i see. btw i think the AWSGlueServiceRole is too "powerful" to use in production but anyways...i just want to mention that this error could also be the result of s3 rate limiting: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=929801

Comment: Yeah that's possible, in my case we weren't anywhere near enough requests to cause an issue. If the production role is too powerful you can just look at what its permissions are and pair them down until they're acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same issue today and it turn out that not only you need read/write permission to the corresponding bucket/path in the IAM Role policy used for the Glue job, but also the s3:DeleteObject such that the job could clean up the `_temporary` directory. The error message basically says it failed not on write but on delete step.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```